# I need to create databse tabel for invoice

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

Im doing a project for restaurant.so in it i need invoice tabel in database.in invoise there are multiple items like mango juice and fried rice, like wise.the amount of items are different for each bills.so how i create my in database.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! before you post questions, please put some effort and do some research to solve the problems. there are many tutorial sites that you can refer.

Comment: Learn SQL: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sort of a generic table structure that might help get you started:

tblInvoice:
InvNum
InvDate
InvTime
InvRepNum
InvSubtotal
InvSalesTax
InvShipping
InvTotal
InvNotes
InvPaidDate

tblInvoiceDetail:
InvDetailNum
InvDetailInvNum
InvDetailProdNum
InvDetailProdDescr
InvDetailProdPrice
InvDetailQty
InvDetailLineTotal

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question, here is a simple database design:

- You would have a table that stores all the products: Product that a customer can order using your app.
- Then, you will have a table that stores all the orders: Order
- You would then store all the ordered products in a table: OrderedProducts
- Then you would have a table for storing invoices: Invoice. This will hold all the order ids.

ps: not posting the actual script because its better if the person does some research with this knowledge.